# glue job schema inference issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

**Requirment:** I need a glue job to get the aws-dynamodb(nested structure-combination of maps and list) data into s3.

My approach: First, i used glue-dynamic frame to get all the data from dynamodb  into one dynamic frame.

```
datasource = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
             "dynamodb",
              connection_options={
                 "dynamodb.input.tableName": table_name,
                 "dynamodb.throughput.read.percent": read_percentage,
                 "dynamodb.splits": "100",
    }
)
```

after using this, i got `datasource` dynamic frame with all the data.

here i want to do some sort of transformation and want to perform some filters, so thats why i used pyspark dataframe concept.

```
df0 = datasource.toDF()
```

my input dataframe `df0` contains json data `collection` in the struct format, so i used `to_json` to convert struct into json-string. here i need json string not the struct.

```
df1 = df0.select(to_json("collection"))
```

from `df1`, i am accessing whatever i want.

**Major Issue**

some of the attributes present in the collection are appearing like this

```
collection : { 
              "name" : "aaa",
               "id" : "111" ,
               "address" : "some address",
               "price" : 
                        {"string" : 1212.0 },
               "retailer" :
                         {"string" : "xxxx"},
               "categories" : "array": [
                                       "7216"
                                       ]
}
```

if you see above example `price`,`reatiler`,`categories`, datatypes are appearing as a nested attribute.

**i want output like this**

```
collection : { 
              "name" : "aaa",
               "id" : "111" ,
               "address" : "some address",
               "price" : "1212.0",
               "retailer" :"xxxx",
               "categories" : "[7216]"
}
```

**How can i resolve this, please let me know**

Comment: Have you tried passing make_cols as shown in  https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/resolve_choice.md#the-make_cols-option ?

Comment: I tried using Glue-ResolveChoice option, it solves my issue

Comment: I have posted the answer. Please mark it as answered if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing is expected behaviour as Glue gives you choice to chose what datatype you want for a column with ambiguous types within a DynamicFrame.

[ResolveChoice](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/resolve_choice.md#4-revisiting-the-string-int-choice-type-in-the-data) provides information for resolving ambiguous types within a DynamicFrame with multiple [options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-ResolveChoice.html).

Depending on your requirement you can chose any of this option and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution maybe to change the types of your columns using the [Map transformation that applies a function to all records of a DynamicFrame](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map.html):

```py
inputDyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    ...
)

def mapping(record: Dict[str, Any]):
    record["SomeVal"] = int(record["SomeVal"])
    # ... put, del and other dict operations
    return record 

mapped_dyF = Map.apply(frame=inputDyf, f=mapping)
```